# MaterializeCSS - How to close the mobile menu

Tags: jquery, materialize

I use the framework CSS Materialize, but I have a problem. How can I close the left-mobile-menu when I click in a link ? By default the menu closes only when you click outside the menu. So I tried with the fonction removeMenu() but it doesn't work. Anyone has a solution ? This is my menu :

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
      <nav class="orange darken-4" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
          <a id="logo-container"  class="brand-logo"><img id="class" src="img/logo.png" class="nav_logo"></a>
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a>test</a></li>
            <li ><a>test2</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
            <li><a>test</a></li>
            <li><a>test2</a></li>
          </ul>
          <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse" id="burger_menu"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: I found the solution :$("#nav-mobile li").click(function() {
          $('.button-collapse').sideNav('hide');
      });

Comment: Might want to add it as an answer. It's actually documented [here](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html#options).

Answer (score 8):

Add `closeOnClick`

```
// Initialize collapse button
$('.button-collapse').sideNav({
    menuWidth: 300, // Default is 240
    edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
    closeOnClick: true // Closes side-nav on <a> clicks, useful for Angular/Meteor
  }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on the fact that both answers use jquery, I decided to add an additional answer that just uses the class of the `sidenav` elements to close the navigation element.

You can find the sidenav documentation on the [materializecss.com](https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html) homepage. It states:

> Add the class  `.sidenav-close` to an element inside the `sidenav` and any
>   click event on that element will cause the `sidenav` to close. This is
>   useful in Single Page Apps where the page does not refresh on link
>   clicks.

Usage from the documentation:

```
<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
    <li><a class="sidenav-close" href="#!">Clicking this will close Sidenav</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

No jquery, js function is needed.

Refer [this official documentation](https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html#options) Scroll down to **Close Trigger**, using the `.sidenav-close` will do the work for you.

In case the link gets obsolete this is what worked for me.

```
<ul className="sidenav" id="mobile-links">
   <li className="sidenav-close">Home Page</li>
   <li className="sidenav-close">Dashboard</li>
   <li className="sidenav-close">About Us</li>
   <li className="sidenav-close">Contact Us</li>
   <li className="sidenav-close">Logout</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi globefire. Please consider adding more information because if the link becomes obsolete, this answer doesn't add any value.

Comment: Hey, @TiagoMartinsPeres thanks for your guidance. I will make sure to do this in all my future answers

Answer (score 2):

The documented solution did not work for me either. I had to resort to some 'hacking'. Here is how I got to do it.

I added a button to the side-nav with `id="side-nav-clear"`, on click of that button I trigger a click on the `sidenav-overlay`, which is how the user would normally hide the side-nav. This works as expected for me.

```
$("#side-nav-clear").on("click", function() {
    $("#sidenav-overlay").trigger("click");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Good one ! Thanks